# TWRP recovery installed but not opening

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot-loop

I have Vivo y15s , I rooted my phone with fastboot (oem unlock)
I installed TWRP recovery.img using fastboot 
But 
My phone is not starting and TWRP recovery mode is not opening.
Only Fast Boot mode is working..

Comment: did you installed latest twrp for your device?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you might have flashed the wrong TWRP image. TWRP images are specific per device. Look for your device here:
https://twrp.me/Devices/

If you find the correct one, then reflash stock OS, then oem unlock, then flash new recovery.